# how to setup datepicker using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create date functionality using jquery on start date and end date controls. i want to select start date and when coming to end date before the start date , the previous date will come as disable my code is below.

```
$( "#" + TxtStrtDate,"#" + TxtExpDte" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        var option = this.id == "abc" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",

        instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
            instance.settings.dateFormat ||
        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
        selectedDate, instance.settings );

        dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
    }
});
```

what is the mistake in my code please suggest.

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing your html. What are the controls you are trying to link to?

Comment: waht is problem in myquestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned that these were server controls, I assume you are using ASP.NET. If this is the case and you are using MasterPages, MasterPages mangle the id of the control so you have to do the following:

```
$('#<%= TxtStrtDate.ClientID %>, #<%= TxtExpDte.ClientID %>').datepicker({
...
});
```

Otherwise, you have an extra " in your selector and your ids need to be within the quotes unless they are actually javascript variables:

```
$( "#" + TxtStrtDate,"#" + TxtExpDte" )
```

should be changed to:

```
$("#TxtStrtDate, #TxtExpDte")
// or if they are javascript variables
$("#" + TxtStrtDate + ", #" + TxtExpDte)
```

**Edit**:

Per your comment, it seems that you want to use the date range version of the jquery datepicker. For that you will have to do the following:

```
$( "#TxtStrtDate" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#TxtExpDte" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }
});
$( "#TxtExpDte" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#TxtStrtDate" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    }
});
```

Checkout the [date range demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range) on the jquery ui site for more information.

Comment: ya i m using asp.net. im using ascx page.in ascx page i alredy taken as var TxtStrtDate = '<%=TxtStrtDate.ClientID%>';
   var TxtExpDte= '<%=TxtExpDte.ClientID%>';                                                  but on my js script page in not working properly as i m want.plz give the solution for me

Comment: its working but in start date it select the values but when i am select the date ,it does not hide.in expiry date it shows the previous months .how i m solve this problem

Comment: it working but in start date box ,why the previous months are come for example if current month is june then why may is come?

Comment: @user1196392 By default May is not an option unless you allow the user to change months. You can remove the option to change months if you wish. You can even check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MsFh2/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `TxtStrtDate` and `TxtExpDte` are variables, the way you are referring the elements is invalid.

**Update to this:**

```
$("#"+TxtStrtDate+", #"+TxtExpDte).datepicker({
...
});
```

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/PQfDc/) with the suggest code works just fine!

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/PQfDc/1/) with out current code proves that it does not work!

---

**If they are in fact the elements IDs, use:**

```
$("#TxtStrtDate, #TxtExpDte").datepicker({
...
});
```

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/PQfDc/2/) Example!

Comment: @JoshMein Well, no, there's actually an extra quote in the original, but other than that it was ok.

Comment: @JoshMein (My original comment got chopped off, but wouldn't this work as well?)

Comment: @JoshMein, well, help was provided with many case scenarios. It's up with the OP to express himself and allow us to provide better assistance.

Comment: Your new edits are correct. Initially you did not mention the javascript variables and from the wording of the question it did not seem that they user had javascript variables. The only key issue will be whether they are in fact server controls and if this could cause an issue because of an asp.net master page mangling the ids.

Comment: @Zuul +1 Your answer is now complete and will cover most scenarios, and I agree, it is up to the OP to give us more information. Could you remove some of the unecessary comments that are cluttering your question :)

Comment: @Dave Newton My original comments were prior to his edits. They were initially lacking information and seemed incorrect when comparing to what the OP was asking. In the current version, I agree with his answer in its entirety.

Comment: @JoshMein Well yeah, so were mine.